# Passing whole object instance (that contains an empty List<string>) from View -> Controller results in List.Count==1 in Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a view that pretty much does this:

```
@foreach (var object in @Model)
{
     //display wishList values
     @Html.ActionLink("Edit Object", "Edit", "Object", @object)
}
```

the 'object' class:

```
public class Object
{
   public Object()
   {
       this.ObjectList = new List<string>();
   }

   public List<string> ObjectList {get;set;}
   public string Title {get;set;}
}
```

Inside the foreach in View, Object.ObjectList is initialized but Count == 0;
When i pass it to the controller action which is this:

```
public ActionResult Edit(Object object)
{
     //do stuff
}
```

The problem is, the object inside the Edit() action, has the Title set correctly, but the List apparently has a new entry (Count == 1) which is this:

```
"System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use explicit `for` loop instead of a `foreach` loop, and reference your elements by their index

Have a look at this:

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

It's a bit old but still applies.